# Client accessing SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, windows, client

SQL Server database is running in the server computer.

The application in the client computer should access the database in the server.
Just the simple LAN connection is fine? Or any other settings are needed?

OS used: Windows 7
Front End: VB.NET
Back End: SQL SERVER

Comment: SQL SERVER can be accessible in Network using ITS Instance Name

Answer (score 0):

You also need any firewalls between the client and server to be open on the SQL Server port (default 1433). On LANs the usual transport protocol is TCP; check that that protocol is enabled too.

And you need the SQL Server instance to allow either your LAN Id or a SQL Server logon access to the DB (your Connection String will indicate which method you're using; see [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com) if in doubt).